# How can I make that my button 1 takes me to my third activity?

Tags: android

I have two buttons on the main screen. When I click the sad one it works, but when I click on the happy one it doesn't work("Feliz" button). I have tried everything and really I don't know where to put the codes or what. Here is what I have:

```
package com.example.clara;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Button btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btn1:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Yaaay",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                Intent tristeza = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(tristeza);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Noooo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;



        }
    }
}
```

I removed the methods but still doesn't work. Here is the manifest for this app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clara">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/claralinda">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:background="#0c3d46"
        android:text="@string/Hola"
        android:textColor="#c1f1ab"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="220dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:background="#0c3d46"
        android:text="@string/second_page"
        android:textColor="#71cfae"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.101"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="220dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:background="#0c3d46"
        android:text="@string/second_page_sad"
        android:textColor="#71cfae"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.902"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text2" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Remove the methods of openThirdActivity() and openSecondActivity() and try again.

Comment: What is the duplicate code in switch case? You care writing both start activity intent and calling the methods, which do the same thing. Remove one of them in both the case statements.

Comment: Okay, so I removed the duplicate code in switch case(the methods of open Third and second activity) but still only the second button works. I think it has to do with the manifest.

Comment: Post your code as it is now.

Comment: Your activity_main.xml layout probably have a different id for the happy one which isn't binded yet to you activity. Please add the layout to your question.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך There you have it :)

Comment: Your `activity_main.xml` seems correct. Have you check if your happy activity is correct?  You can always running a single activity to check it by right clicking on it and select Run.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I run it separately and it says that the activity muss be exported or contain an intent filter? Where should I put it?

Comment: add `android:exported=true`, something like this `<activity
    android:name=".ThirdActivity"
    android:exported="true" />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
</application>
```